# JdbcTemplate Mockito ClassCastException

Tags: spring, junit, mockito, classcastexception

I am trying to mock a method of the Spring framework's `JdbcTemplate` class. The method has the following signature:

```
public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, Class<T> requiredType) throws DataAccessException {...}
```

The mocking is being done as mentioned below:

```
when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(anyString(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn("data");
```

However, this call throws the following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer$ClassWithSuperclassToWorkAroundCglibBug$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$ce187d66 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at test.DaoJdbcTest.setUp(DaoJdbcTest.java:81)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
```

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance~

**EDIT:**

Here's the full code:

```
public class DaoJdbc extends NamedParameterJdbcSupport {
    public String query(String sql) {
        return getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, String.class);
    }
}

public class DaoJdbcTest {
    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_SMART_NULLS)
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private DaoJdbc dao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        dao = new DaoJdbc();
        dao.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);

        Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(anyString(), Matchers.eq(String.class))).thenReturn("data");
    }

    @Test
    public void testQuery() {
        String ret = dao.query("select 'test' from dual");

        assertEquals("data", ret);

        verify(jdbcTemplate).queryForObject(anyString(), eq(String.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: The full code is required for debugging this, but the larger question is why are you mocking out the JdbcTemplate?  My advice would be to test against an embedded DB.  Mocks are fine in most places, but not for data store access.

Comment: I edited my original post with code details. I have been using mocks for jdbc templates for a while and haven't run into any issues so far. I will definitely look at using embedded DB but at this point, I'm short on time. This issue seems to me to be a syntactical issue, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the answer = Answers.RETURNS_SMART_NULLS.  Test passes when I remove that.  What does that feature do?  The default null behavior works fine for me.

As a bonus, you can also use the MockitoJunitRunner to clean up the code a bit...

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DaoJdbcTest {
    @Mock
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private DaoJdbc dao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(anyString(), Matchers.eq(String.class))).thenReturn("data");
    }

    @Test
    public void testQuery() {
        String ret = dao.query("select 'test' from dual");

        assertEquals("data", ret);

        verify(jdbcTemplate).queryForObject(anyString(), eq(String.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed it does .. thanks! As far as I know, answer is used to define the return value for unstubbed invocations. I also found out that the test will pass without removing the answer if the other format is used: `Mockito.doReturn("data").when(jdbcTemplate).queryForObject(anyString(), Matchers.eq(String.class));`; not sure what the difference is.